# In webview how to get the value of a variable by using its ID to a string.

Tags: javascript, java, android, string, webview

I am entering the username and password using-

```
myWebView.loadUrl
("javascript:document.getElementById
('username').value='"+ user + "';");
```

After that login button will be pressed. The website then displays a message that login was successful. I want to retrieve that message in a string so that i can further use it to display a notification.

I know the id of the element in which the message is stored, so i want to know how can i extract the value of that specific element.